# is it possible to use a variable filter?

Tags: angularjs

I'm trying to use filter who gonna change depending on a click or write on an input.

```
<input
  name="hotelinput"
  type="text"
  ng-keydown="changeFilterToKeyPressed()"
  ng-click="changeFilterToClicked()">

<div ng-repeat="hotel in filteredHotels = (hotels | VARIABLEFILTER | orderBy: 'country') track by $index">
    ...
</div>
```

I know that you can do filter:variable and change it in the controller but I need to change the full filter for one of my custom filters every time.

Answer (score 1):

I didn't tested it but something like this could be possible

#### JS

```
if(x){
  $scope.VARIABLEFILTER = $filter('myCustomFilter')
} else {
  $scope.VARIABLEFILTER = $filter('myCustomFilter2')
}
```

---

I made it to work and rewrote the filter I once did in other question
http://plnkr.co/edit/LuA3hYr7mImihYnVIxqQ

```
  .filter('applyFilter', function($filter) {
    return function(input, filterToApply) {
      return filterToApply === undefined ? input : $filter(filterToApply)(input)
    }
  })
```

I hope that's what you were looking for

Comment: Looks like didn't work. And I need to pass parameters anyway. Like myCustomFilter:anything.

Answer (score 0):

You need ngChange instead of ngClick

```
<input
  name="hotelinput"
  type="text"
  ng-model="filterKey"
  ng-change="changeFilterToKeyPressed()"
  ng-focus="changeFilterToClicked()">
```

and update your function changeFilterToKeyPressed

```
$scope.changeFilterToKeyPressed = function() {
    $scope.VARIABLEFILTER = someUpdatesWhichYouWant($scope.filterKey); //You can use filterKey on any change
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what are you trying to do and how is related to my question.

Comment: no problem if its not a answer of your problem then im going to delete it.

Comment: I don't know if it's an answer or not, I just didn't understand. A better explanation is appreciated.